# Parse xml data saved in table column into multiple columns - PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml, mysqli

I have a table column that contains XML string. I need to parse the data from each row (XML string column) and insert it into a different table where columns are actually the tags from that XML.

so lets say "tableA.xmlcolumn" contains:

```
<xml>
    <tag-a>bla bla bla</tag-a>
    <tag-b>bla bla bla</tag-b>
    <tag-c>bla bla bla</tag-c>
</xml>
```

Into

"tableB"

```
tag-a       | tag-b       | tag-c
---------------------------------------
bla bla bla | bla bla bla | bla bla bla
```

TableA have 300K~ rows

How would you approach this using PHP/MySQL?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `xml_parse_into_struct` to get XML into an associative array and then you can add to your database table.

Comment: Thanks! actually I was aiming to get if there's a bit more "sophisticated" way than just select > parse in php > insert

Comment: "sophisticated" means? Do you want me to write the whole code for you?

Comment: no. I meant maybe by doing in all using SQL (no php) if possible... or maybe it would be faster/efficient to select all the data and and write a procedure to parse and insert at the same time. I know how to do it, I just think it would take a long time or maybe I'll run out of memory by doing each row with select > php > insert

Comment: ohh.. Let me look for that, if there is SQL option to parse XML.

Comment: I don't believe the examples cited as suitable candidates to answer the question are exact duplicates- they deal with importing xml from a file or string rather than a pure sql solution to reading, processing and inserting xml data and was about to post a suitable answer :(